# How to clean this Sql data up?

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is a follow on question to a [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834247/need-some-help-trying-to-do-a-simple-sql-insert-with-some-simple-data-checking).

I have the following data in a single db table.

```
Name                LeftId    RightId
------------------------------------------
Cat                     1  
Cat                     1
Dog                     2
Dog                     2
Dog                               3
Dog                               3
Gerbil                  4         5 
Cat                
Bird
Cow                     6
Cow
Cow                               7
Dog                     8         9
```

Note that some rows have NO data for for LeftId and RightId.

Now, what i wish to do is find two different queries

1. All rows which have at least 1 Id in one of the two columns AND row with NO data in both of those two Id columns.

eg.

```
Cat     1
Cow     6 (or 7 .. i'm not worried)
```

2. All the rows where LeftId and RightId are NULL grouped by the same name. If another row (with the same name) has a value in the LeftId or RightId, this this name will not be returned.

eg.

```
Bird
```

hmm..

EDIT: Reworded the first question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first query, you want rows that answer to both of the following criteria:

1. The `Name` in the row appears in the table in the same row in which `LeftId` and `RightId` are both NULL.
2. The `Name` in the row appears in the table in same row where at at least one of `LeftId` and `RightId` is *not* NULL.

Well, #1 is done by:

```
SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NULL) AND (RightId IS NULL)
```

And #2 is done by:

```
SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NOT NULL) OR (RightId IS NOT NULL)
```

You could **intersect** them to see which `Name`s appear in both lists:

```
SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NULL) AND (RightId IS NULL)
INTERSECT
SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NOT NULL) OR (RightId IS NOT NULL)
```

Which returns:

```
Name
----
Cat
Cow
```

But you want the `LeftId` and `RightId`, and you don't care which, so I guess we'll aggregate on the Name:

```
SELECT Name, MIN(LeftId) AS LeftId, MIN(RightId) AS RightId 
    FROM Tbl WHERE Tbl.Name IN (
      SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NULL) AND (RightId IS NULL)
      INTERSECT
      SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NOT NULL) OR (RightId IS NOT NULL)
    )
GROUP BY Name
```

Which returns

```
Name  LeftId  RightId
----  ------  -------
Cat   1
Cow   6       7
```

[lc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867030/how-to-clean-this-sql-data-up/867069#867069) already suggested using COALESE to turn those two IDs to a single one. So how about this:

```
SELECT Name, COALESCE(MIN(LeftId),MIN(RightId)) AS Id 
    FROM Tbl WHERE Tbl.Name IN (
      SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NULL) AND (RightId IS NULL)
      INTERSECT
      SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NOT NULL) OR (RightId IS NOT NULL)
    )
GROUP BY Name
```

Which returns:

```
Name  Id
----  --
Cat   1
Cow   6
```

---

For the second query, you want rows that obey the following criteria:

1. The `Name` appears only in rows that have no `LeftId` and `RightId`

I can't think of a way to do that sort of self-referencing query in SQL in a single set of criteria, so I'll break it down to two criteria. *Both* must be obeyed to be acceptable:

1. The `Name` appears in rows that have no `LeftId` and `RightId`
2. The `Name` does *not* appear in rows that have either `LeftId` or `RightId`

Doing #1 is simply:

```
SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NULL) AND (RightId IS NULL)
```

But #2 is tricky. Of course doing the opposite of #2 ("all the `Name` that appear in rows that have either `LeftId` or `RightId`) is just like before:

```
SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NOT NULL) OR (RightId IS NOT NULL)
```

Now comes the tricky bit - we want all the rows that obey #1 but don't obey the opposite of #2. This is where **EXCEPT** is useful:

```
SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NULL) AND (RightId IS NULL)
EXCEPT
SELECT Name FROM Tbl WHERE (LeftId IS NOT NULL) OR (RightId IS NOT NULL)
```

Which returns:

```
Name
----
Bird
```

Which is what we wanted!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then this is fairly trivial:

1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE (LeftId IS NOT NULL 
AND RightId IS NULL)
OR
(LeftId IS NULL 
AND RightId IS NOT NULL)
```

2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
              (SELECT * FROM your_table y1
               WHERE (y1.LeftId IS NOT NULL OR y1.RightId IS NOT NULL)
               AND y1.name = your_table.name)
```

If this isn't right then perhaps you could clarify.

Edit: updated

Comment: the second one is not right. For that query, i'm after all rows (grouped by name) which none of those (per group) have an Id. So in your code, a Cow has one row with both nulls, but it also has some other rows with one of those fields having a number. as such, a Cow should not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE (LeftID IS NULL AND RightID IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (LeftID IS NOT NULL AND RightID IS NULL)
```

Query 2)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE LeftID IS NULL AND RightID IS NULL
```

Comment: Nope :( I reworded the two q's again. maybe that might help/clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly here.

Query 1:

```
SELECT t1.Name, COALESCE(MIN(t1.LeftID), MIN(t1.RightID))
FROM Table t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT t2.Name
             FROM Table t2
             WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name 
             AND   t2.LeftID IS NULL AND t2.RightID IS NULL)
AND   COALESCE(MIN(t1.LeftID), MIN(t1.RightID)) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT t1.Name
FROM Table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT t2.Name
                 FROM Table t2
                 WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name
                 AND   (t2.LeftID IS NOT NULL OR t2.RightID IS NOT NULL))
```

Comment: 1st query doesn't run in sql2008.

Comment: You would do much better to give the error you get. "It doesn't run" gives us absolutely nothing to go by and we cannot help you. However, I think I can guess you need a GROUP BY clause because of the aggregate functions MIN() and that's the error you're getting. I edited the answer so try again.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1:

```
SELECT [Name], [LeftID], [RightID]

FROM [TestTable]

WHERE -- "All rows which have at least 1 Id in one of the two columns"
      ([LeftID] IS NOT NULL OR [RightID] IS NOT NULL)
      OR
      -- "Rows with NO data in both of those two Id columns"
      ([LeftID] IS NULL AND [RightID] IS NULL)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT [Name], [LeftID], [RightID]

FROM [TestTable]

WHERE -- "All the rows where LeftId and RightId are NULL
      -- grouped by the same name"
      ([LeftID] IS NULL AND [RightID] IS NULL)
      AND
      -- "If another row (with the same name) has a value
      -- in the LeftId or RightId, this name will not be returned"    
      ([Name] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM [TestTable]
                      WHERE [LeftID] IS NOT NULL
                            OR
                            [RightID] IS NOT NULL))

GROUP BY [Name], [LeftID], [RightID]
```

Results:

```
Name                                               LeftID      RightID
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
Cat                                                1           NULL
Cat                                                1           NULL
Dog                                                2           NULL
Dog                                                2           NULL
Dog                                                NULL        3
Dog                                                NULL        3
Gerbil                                             4           5
Cat                                                NULL        NULL
Bird                                               NULL        NULL
Cow                                                6           NULL
Cow                                                NULL        NULL
Cow                                                NULL        7
Dog                                                8           9

(13 row(s) affected)

Name                                               LeftID      RightID
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
Bird                                               NULL        NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```